# How to merge two eloquent model result attributes as new result in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel product model that has a relation called details.
I want to merge the attributes of these two eloquent results together.

My $product attributes are like this:

```html
#attributes: array:7 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "title" => "test"
    "slug" => "test"
    "html" => null
    "published_at" => "2022-01-27 11:01:00"
    "created_at" => "2022-01-27 11:04:15"
    "updated_at" => "2022-01-27 11:05:30"
  ]
```

Also $product->details attributes are like this:

```html
#attributes: array:6 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "model" => "test"
    "sku" => "test"
    "base_price" => null
    "created_at" => "2022-01-27 11:04:15"
    "updated_at" => "2022-01-27 11:05:30"
  ]
```

What I need is this result:

```html
#attributes: array:10 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "title" => "test"
    "slug" => "test"
    "html" => null
    "model" => "test"
    "sku" => "test"
    "base_price" => null
    "published_at" => "2022-01-27 11:01:00"
    "created_at" => "2022-01-27 11:04:15"
    "updated_at" => "2022-01-27 11:05:30"
  ]
```

Notice that these are the eloquent results and are not a simple array.

Comment: Have a look at the Laravel [`Collections`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) documentation, specifically the [`merge`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-merge) method.

Comment: is it a one to one relation?

Comment: I tried merge but it doesn't work! When I create two custom collections it works.

Comment: @N69S Yes it's one to one relation.

Comment: I get this error when merging results: `Call to undefined method App\Models\Product::merge()`

Comment: add the code you tried, and i suggest you get the product with the detail attached to it then run the `map()` collection method to format the result.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the formatting using a [API Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources) class or simply by using a `map()` function depending on your project/preference. The API Resource may look something like this:

```php
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ProductResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'slug' => $this->slug,
            'html' => $this->html,
            "model" => $this->details?->model,
            "sku" => $this->details?->sku,
            "base_price" => $this->details?->base_price,
            ...
        ];
    }
}
```